# How to change back to my old environment path in Windows

Tags: mysql, path, xampp, composer-php, environment

I was just looking to get started with Composer. I downloaded it and it changed my path, now my current XAMPP websites won't work. How do I revert back to my old PATH, i'm not even sure what it would be. It's beyond my experience right now.

I get this error:`No connection could be made because the target machine actively (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306)`

Looking at my XAMPP controller, it won't start MySql services, I just get Error: mysql service could not be started [-1]

Jonnny

Comment: How did you change your path? Do you remember how it was before the change? You probably can repair it with a simple restart of the machine.

Comment: I don't remember what it was before. Composer just popped up and said it had changed my PATH. I incidental did restart my machine for some updates and Mysql wont start, but Apache has been fine.

Comment: The Composer installation for windows is supposed to simply add one more path with their executable, and nothing more. I wonder why it broke something.

Comment: I followed a lot of similar questions on super user about reverting back to previous versions of the system. In my case I either didn't have them or couldn't access them. So I just uninstalled Xampp after backing up the xampp folder and reinstalled. So far at least my Mysql and Apache server are working ok. I was looking to upgrade my XAMPP version as is as I was running php 5.2 and wanted at least 5.4 so it was ok in my situation.